# PDO exibindo a query preenchida

Tags: php, pdo, php-7

Bom, tenho a seguinte **função**:

```
public function inserir (ClientesModelos $_cliente) : bool {

        $sql = 'INSERT INTO clientes 
(data, nome, sobreNome, nascimento, documento, telefone, celular, email, senha, bloqueio) 
VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)';

        $inserir = $this->pdo->prepare ($sql);

        $inserir->bindValue (1, $_cliente->getData()->format("Y-m-d 00:00:00"));
        $inserir->bindValue (2, $_cliente->getNome());
        $inserir->bindValue (3, $_cliente->getSobreNome());
        $inserir->bindValue (4, $_cliente->getNascimento()->format("Y-m-d 00:00:00"));
        $inserir->bindValue (5, $_cliente->getDocumento());
        $inserir->bindValue (6, $_cliente->getTelefone());
        $inserir->bindValue (7, $_cliente->getCelular());
        $inserir->bindValue (8, $_cliente->getEmail());
        $inserir->bindValue (9, $_cliente->getSenha());
        $inserir->bindValue (10, $_cliente->getBloqueio());

        return $inserir->execute();

    }
```

A string **sql** está com (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)

Gostaria de saber como eu faço imprimir a **saída** da **query** **string** já com **?** (**interrogações**) preenchidos.

Tipo:

```
  INSERT INTO clientes (
  data, 
  nome, 
  sobreNome, 
  nascimento, 
  documento, 
  telefone, 
  celular, 
  email, 
  senha, 
  bloqueio
) VALUES (
  '2010-05-05',
  'José',
  'Miguel',
  '2000-10-10',
  '1111111111',
  '11111111111',
  '1111111111',
  'aa@bb.com',
  'senha',
  'não'
)
```

Comment: O [`PDOStatement::debugDumpParams`](https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/pdostatement.debugdumpparams.php) não é suficiente?

Comment: seria print_r($inserir->debugDumpParams);?

Comment: Não consegui o que eu queria aquela resposta!